# How to check CSV file header

Tags: python, csv

say I have two dict

```
dict1 = {'name':'Leo','age':'15','tel':'123456789'}
dict2 = {'name':'Zac','age':'20','tel':'987654321'}
```

I want to write these two dicts to a csv file. I can write a dict to a csv file with header located at the top of table, but when I add second dict to the same csv file, it writes another header after last inputs. So I'd like to know if there's a way to check if header already exists, if no, add header, else just add new dict data

Answer (score 6):

It's not clear what your question is, so I'm going to have to guess. If you want a more specific answer, instead of vague generalities, you will need to write a more specific question.

I suspect you have some code like this:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    dw = csv.DictWriter(f, ('name', 'age', 'tel'))
    dw.writeheader()
    dw.writerow(dict1)

with open('output.csv', 'a') as f:
    dw = csv.DictWriter(f, ('name', 'age', 'tel'))
    dw.writeheader()
    dw.writerow(dict2)
```

And the problem is that your output looks like this:

```
name,age,tel
Leo,15,123456789
name,age,tel
Zac,20,987654321
```

When you wanted this:

```
name,age,tel
Leo,15,123456789
Zac,20,987654321
```

If so, the right way to solve this is to just not call `writeheader` the second time. Depending on how your code is structured, this might be as simple as just not calling it somewhere.

But let's say you've got some wrapper function, like this:

```
def add_to_csv(row):
    with open('output.csv', 'a') as f:
        dw = csv.DictWriter(f, ('name', 'age', 'tel'))
        dw.writeheader()
        dw.writerow(row)
```

And you can't change it, and you want it to write the header only if the file is empty.

There are a few different ways to tell if a file is empty. One easy once, given that you've got the file open in `'a'` mode, is to just check that `f.tell()` is nonzero. Or you can check that `os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size` is nonzero.

But if you're doing all of the writes within one run of the program, it's probably cleaner to just keep track within the script. Again, you can move the `open` and `DictWriter` code out to the instance/global level instead of local to the function/method. Or you can add an instance/global flag that keeps track of whether you've called `writeheader` yet.

Answer (score 0):

sure

```
headers_that_do_not_exist = set(dict2.keys()) - set(dict1.keys())
```

Comment: I don't know exactly what the OP is asking for, but it can't possibly be this. His two dicts have exactly the same keys, so this would always be an empty set. Plus, he's trying to write `dict2` to a CSV file, so writing just the new headers (if there are any) wouldn't do anything useful.

Comment: yeah I assume you are closer to what the OP wanted ... I didnt understand the question very well I think ...

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough in there to understand the question very well… I'm assuming that he much be asking _something_ sensible that has something to do with CSV files, and probably with `DictWriter`… but it's hard to get farther than that.